# Problem with Renewal process and holding times.

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

Let $(N_t)_{t \geq 0}$ be a ordinary renewal process, i.e. the interarrival times of the processes jumps say $(T_k-T_{k-1})_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ is an i.i.d sequence.

In an example in my book on the subject they consider a function $Z(t)=E(T_{N_t+1}-t)$. Then it says "Consider $E(T_{N_t+1}-t|T_1=s)$. If $s \leq t$ then $E(T_{N_t+1}-t|T_1=s)=Z(t-s)$. [...]."

I have tried to prove the last equality for some hours now, but i cant seem to formalize it. Would a kind soul, show how to prove this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Conditionally on $T_1=s$, the process $(N_{t+s})_{t\geqslant0}$ is distributed as $(1+N_t)_{t\geqslant0}$ hence $T_{N_{t+s}}$ is distributed, conditionally on $T_1=s$, as $T_{1+N_t}+s$, unconditionally.

In particular $E(T_{N_{t+s}}\mid T_1=s)=E(T_{1+N_t}+s)$ hence $E(T_{N_{t+s}}-(t+s)\mid T_1=s)=E(T_{1+N_t}-t)=Z(t)$ for every $s\geqslant0$, as desired.

Comment: I am not sure how to prove that $T_{N_{t+s}}|T_1=s$ is equal in distribution to $T_{1+N_t}+s$, would you care to elaborate? Anyway everything else makes sense, thanks for that!

Comment: As written explicitely, this holds because $N_{t+s}$ conditionally on $T_1=s$ is distributed as $1+N_t$, which in turn is exactly the strong Markov property at time $T_1$ under the form that $N_{t+T_1}-N_{T_1}$ is distributed as $N_t$.